# If I use -Wextra option with gcc, I don't need to use -Wall?

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-warnings

Does `-Wextra` also enable `-Wall`, and does `-Wall` also enable `-W` in GCC?

Answer (score 1):

`-Wextra` is a replacement to the old `-W` flag. It enables some **extra** warnings which are not enabled by `-Wall`, and does not enable `-Wall` by itself - if you want both, you'll have to use `-Wall -Wextra`.